# Requeue the Spring amqp message with updated properties

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a use case where i have to re-queue the message with updated properties , Messages are getting re queued but message properties are not getting updated

```
public class TestListener implements MessageListener{


@Override
public void onMessage(Message arg0) {

    MessageProperties properties = arg0.getMessageProperties();
    int count = properties.getMessageCount();
    System.out.println(count);
    properties.setMessageCount(++count);
    throw new AmqpException("test");
}
```

But the value of count always prints its always as 0

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that - the amqp protocol does not support sending data back when rejecting a message.

You have to republish the message yourself, e.g with a `RabbitTemplate.send()` call.

You should also not use a "system" property for your own purposes; use `messageGetProperties().set("myHeader", count++)`.

Comment: adding the custom properties in header dosn't help as we are getiing the same value. I have a use case where we need to req the message n no of times based on status of some API call i.e public class TestListener implements MessageListener{


@Override
public void onMessage(Message arg0) {

   Byte [] arr = arg0.getBody(); String someValue = new String(arr); // make some API call , if not successful reQ the message( This logic should be tried few number of times) else move forward

Comment: As I said, you can't modify the message while rejecting it you have to republish it. The `messageCount` property is a special read-only property. When using `RabbitTemplate.receive()` methods, it is an estimate of the number of messages in the queue. It is not populated for message listeners. You need to use a custom header and you need to republish the message yourself, you can't just reject it (if you want to modify it).